# How to get operation system where Corona Simulator is working on?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I just want to know is there any method to get OS of the host that runs the Corona Simulator?

I am aware of `system.getInfo("environment") == "simulator"` and `system.getInfo("platform")`.

> In the Corona Simulator, the value returned depends on the skin
>   selected, allowing you to test platform-dependent logic by changing
>   skins.

I am developing on Windows and my simulator skin is set to an Android device but with `system.getInfo("platform")` I can not find the host os(ie Windows).

Comment: Any specific operation systems? Is this just for android or IOS?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: system.getInfo( "androidApiLevel" ) returns the android api level? You can use this to translate into a version code e.g. android api level 26 = Android 8.0 Oreo. I can't find anywhere in the official docs about returning Windows OS that is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the point about you want to know if the simulator is running on Windows, macOS or some other system. Obviously, as you noted, this will get you the platform of the skin.

The system.getInfo() API allows you to get the platform:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/getInfo.html#platform

This will let you know if you're on "android", "ios", "win32", etc.

There are only a few use cases where you would care what the simulator is running on. You want to simulate a final device in most cases. I'm guessing that you are building some tool that a user will run either on Windows or macOS. I would think you would build a .exe for Windows or a macOS binary and distribute that to anyone who wants to use it.

But you can use "architectureInfo" to get the underlying architecture information. If you're on windows it will return something like "x86" or "x64". You can test that in combination with seeing if you're running in the simulator:

```
if system.getInfo( "environment" ) == "simulator" then
    if (system.getInfo("architectureInfo") == "x86" or system.getInfo("architectureInfo") == "x64") then
        print("This simulator is running on Windows")
    elseif (system.getInfo("architectureInfo") == "x86_64" or system.getInfo("architectureInfo") == "i386") then
        print("This simulator is running on macOS")
    end
end
```

See: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/getInfo.html#architectureinfo